# Knapsack Constraint

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, knapsack, cuts

Is the following expression a knapsack constraint?

$ \sum_i a(i) y(i) \ge W$, where $y(i)$ binaries, $a(i),W$ reals.

What confuses me is the $\ge$ sign.

Alternatively, do solvers generate cuts out of this expression?

Comment: If you compliment the variables $y(i)=1-z(i)$, substitute, and rearrange terms, you get a classic knapsack constraint. And yes, solvers generally separate cuts from all available structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you complement the variables $y_i=1−z_i$, substitute, and rearrange terms, you get a classic knapsack constraint. And yes, solvers generally separate cuts from all available structures.

A simple set of valid inequalities (which could be used as cuts) for your “inverted knapsack constraint” are the so-called *knapsack cover inequalities*:
$$
\sum_{i\in N\setminus S}\min \left\{ a_i, W-\sum_{i\in S}a_i\right\}y_i\geq W-\sum_{i\in S}a_i
$$
Here $N$ is the index set for the variables, and $S\subseteq N$ is such that $\sum_{i\in S}a_i<W$. In “[Lifting the Knapsack Cover Inequalities for the Knapsack Polytope](https://www.lancaster.ac.uk/staff/letchfoa/articles/knapsack-cover.pdf)” Letchford and Souli show how to strengthen these inequalities through lifting.

Answer (score 0):

Either you are looking at [knapsack](http://archive.dimacs.rutgers.edu/reconnect/Lafayette/lectures/knaplecture.pdf) cover ($a_i(1-y)_i$ where $y_i=0$) inequality or its part of minimizing [knapsack](https://www.cs.jhu.edu/%7Emdinitz/classes/ApproxAlgorithms/Spring2019/Lectures/lecture24.pdf) problem. Modern solvers will relax the MIP and then may apply cuts like Gomory cuts.